# How to get the value from specific segment using Terser.get() method in case of segment repetition?

Tags: java, hl7

I'm trying to read HL7 messages where I have multiple `ORC` segments. The `terser.get()` method is only getting values for the first `ORC` segment. When trying to read from `/ORDER(2)/ORC-X-X`, the method does not return any value.

```
Terser mesg = new Terser(next);
System.out.println(mesg.get("/ORDER(2)/ORC-2-1"));
```

The method would return the value for `mesg.get("/ORDER/ORC-2-1")`. I expect it also to return for `"/ORDER(2)/ORC-2-1"`.

Terser Full Path:
[image: Terser Full Path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `getOrderReps()` method from `OMS_O05` that would give the repetition number of ORDERS. Also use `OMS_O05` as message type.

```
OMS_O05 omsMsg = (OMS_O05) next;
Terser t = new Terser(omsMsg);
for (int i = 0; i < omsMsg.getORDERReps(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(t.get("/ORDER("+i+")/ORC-2-1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in Terser, but...

According to [documentation](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/util/Terser.html#get-java.lang.String-), following is the description for `String get(String spec)` method:

> Gets the string value of the field specified. See the class docs for syntax of the location spec.
>   If a repetition is omitted for a repeating segment or field, the first rep is used. If the component or subcomponent is not specified for a composite field, the first component is used (this allows one to write code that will work with later versions of the HL7 standard).

where spec is field specification.

With this, as explained [here](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-use-hapi-terser-with-hl7/), you can get the specific component in specific segment with following code:

```
@Test
public void testAccessSegmentRepetitions() throws Exception{
    //First Next of Kin Id
    assertEquals("1", terser.get("NK1(0)-1"));
    //Second Next of Kin Id
    assertEquals("2", terser.get("NK1(1)-1"));
}
```

The input HL7 message is:

```
MSH|^~\\&|hl7Integration|hl7Integration|||||ADT^A01|||2.3|
EVN|A01|20130617154644
PID|1|465 306 5961||407623|Wood^Patrick^^^MR||19700101|1|||High Street^^Oxford^^Ox1 4DP~George St^^Oxford^^Ox1 5AP|||||||
NK1|1|Wood^John^^^MR|Father||999-9999
NK1|2|Jones^Georgie^^^MSS|MOTHER||999-9999
PV1|1||Location||||||||||||||||261938_6_201306171546|||||||||||||||||||||||||20130617134644|||||||||
```

> We can get particular repetitions using the brackets. Depending where we put the brackets we will be retrieving a segment repetition, a field repetition or a component repetition.

Similarly, in your case, following code should work:

```
mesg.get("/ORC(0)-2-1") //This will return value from first occurrence of segment
mesg.get("/ORC(1)-2-1") //This will return value from second occurrence of segment
```

Update for your edit and your comment:

About the `ORDER` stuff, it looks that it is necessary. In that case, use following code:

```
mesg.get("/ORDER(2)/ORC(0)-2-1") //This will return value from first occurrence of segment
mesg.get("/ORDER(2)/ORC(1)-2-1") //This will return value from second occurrence of segment
```